# How to SUM/add the values of two fields in a View?

Tags: views

I have two separate fields in a View:

1. Miles on Engine at Time of Purchase/Delivery (field_engine_hours_at_delivery)
2. Miles added to Engine After Purchase/Delivery (field_util_agg_engine_hours)

(1) is a standard integer field. (2) is fed by an aggregation of many other content items. My view is set to display these two values in a table, side by side.

I would like to now add those two fields to get a "Total Miles on Engine" value for the view. I tried adding a Views PHP field with the following PHP code, but the result that is returned is blank.

Value Code

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_engine_hours_at_delivery'))) + array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_util_agg_engine_hours')));
```

Output Code

> `<?php $display_output = $entity_field_item['value']; ?>`

I'm not very well-versed in PHP, so I'm sure I've got something amiss in that code. Can anyone clarify whether this can be done... and if it can, what I need to change in my code to make it work?

P.S., I also tried this version of the Value Code, but still did not get any result:

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, '$row->field_engine_hours_at_delivery'))) + array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, '$row->field_util_agg_engine_hours')));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work. I left the Value Code field blank and added this code to the Output Code:

```
<?php
print $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_engine_hours_at_delivery['und'][0]['value'] +
$data->field_field_include_utilization_engine[0]['rendered']['#view']->result[0]->field_data_field_engine_utilization_hours_field_engine_utili;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a module for that: [Views Calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc) allows you to SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns in Views.